# Fastest way to update all children on a directed graph (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql, graph

I have a stored procedure for doing some complex calculations on a directed graph. At some point, I need to update recursively an attribute on all children.

```
CREATE TABLE DirectedGraph 
(
    InputNodeID INT NOT NULL,
    OutputNodeID INT NOT NULL,
    IsUpdated bit NOT NULL
)
```

First, the table is populated with all the edges between the nodes and the IsUpdated attribute is computed using a bitwise AND between the values on the input and the output node, i.e. `inputnode.IsUpdated & outputnode.IsUpdated`

The next step, to which my question refers to, is to then update recursively all the edges that come under an edge that has been determined as not being updated. This means that if an edge is found not updated (IsUpdated = 0), all the edges under it must inherit this property, even if the value set at the nodes level was 1.

Now, for some time this was done by creating a recursive CTE for the graph hierarchy which was then used in a left join to update the original table. This has performed pretty well until the graph became huge and started taking tens of minutes.

I have tried different ways to do this update, but after 2 days of heavily trying things and testing on a production graph of 500.000 rows, it looks like a fast_forward cursor is the fastest way to do this:

```
DECLARE @InputNodeID int, @OutputNodeID int
DECLARE c_IsUpdated CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT InputNodeID, OutputNodeID FROM #graph

OPEN c_IsUpdated
FETCH NEXT FROM c_IsUpdated INTO @InputNodeID, @OutputNodeID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    UPDATE p
    SET p.IsUpdated = p.IsUpdated & c.IsUpdated
    FROM #graph p
        INNER JOIN #graph c ON p.OutputNodeID = c.InputNodeID
    WHERE p.InputNodeID = @InputNodeID AND p.OutputNodeID = @OutputNodeID
FETCH NEXT FROM c_IsUpdated INTO @InputNodeID, @OutputNodeID
END
CLOSE c_IsUpdated
DEALLOCATE c_IsUpdated
```

This performs about 20 times faster than the original query that used a recursive CTE, but I'm still trying to find an better performing solution. Is there anything that should work faster on this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can skip the data(IsUpdated = 0) in your CURSOR.

```
DECLARE @InputNodeID int, @OutputNodeID int
DECLARE c_IsUpdated CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT InputNodeID, OutputNodeID FROM #graph WHERE IsUpdated = 1 -- skip IsUpdated=0
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this has sped up my stored procedure even more.